# Phusion passenger Security check update holding connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, passenger, phusion

I am using phusion passenger version 5.1 every day there's security update check is happening which is holding the connection attached the log for reference.What's the use of security check.IF i disable whether this solve the issue or should i run the command of passenger

```
[ N 2020-02-24 06:31:06.4719 13587/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 5035, application /var/lib/raj/
App 30989 stdout: 
App 30989 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not found for current Ruby interpreter.
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:      This library provides various optimized routines that make
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:      Phusion Passenger faster. Please run 'sudo yum install passenger-devel-5.2.1'
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:      so that Phusion Passenger can compile one on the next run.
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 30989 stderr: 
App 30989 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
App 30989 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 30989 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
App 30989 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 30989 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 31075 stdout: 
[ N 2020-02-24 06:54:21.2705 13587/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 31075, application /var/lib/raj/rails-srv/releases/initial_release/rails-srv (production)
[ E 2020-02-24 07:19:32.7365 13587/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:505 ]: Security update check failed: Couldn't connect to server for https://securitycheck.phusionpassenger.com/v1/check.json (if this error persists check your connection security or try upgrading Passenger) (next check in 24 hours)
App 396 stdout: 
App 396 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not found for current Ruby interpreter.
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:      This library provides various optimized routines that make
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:      Phusion Passenger faster. Please run 'sudo yum install passenger-devel-5.2.1'
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:      so that Phusion Passenger can compile one on the next run.
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 396 stderr: 
App 396 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
App 396 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 396 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
App 396 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 396 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 466 stdout: 
[ N 2020-02-24 07:36:28.1279 13587/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 466, application /var/lib/raj/rails-srv/releases/initial_release/rails-srv (production)
App 19802 stdout: 
App 19802 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not found for current Ruby interpreter.
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:      This library provides various optimized routines that make
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:      Phusion Passenger faster. Please run 'sudo yum install passenger-devel-5.2.1'
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:      so that Phusion Passenger can compile one on the next run.
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 19802 stderr: 
App 19802 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
App 19802 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 19802 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.1/rubyext-ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: connect() timed out!
```

Answer (score 2):

The security check introduced in passenger 5.1.0 attempts to connect to securitycheck.phusionpassenger.com to see if a newer version of passenger including security updates exists.

This can be disabled by setting passenger configuration variable *PassengerDisableSecurityUpdateCheck* to *on* [see here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdisablesecurityupdatecheck) after which a web-server restart is required.

Even when that flag is set, on the first client request after the restart, download & build attempts follow. I found that in a private network (no internet access) this can block apache for approx 20 seconds. However these two steps can be successfully disabled via
environment flags in your webserver config, as indicated in the log messages in your post. For apache this worked for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   PassengerDisableSecurityUpdateCheck on
   SetEnv PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY 0
   SetEnv PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY 0
...
```

Following a web-server re-start, the log now shows:

```
App 23626 stdout: 
App 23626 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not compiling because PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0
App 23626 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not downloading because PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0
App 23626 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 23626 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
```

.. and client connections to the server responded without delay following the re-start.